# Insert value dynamically in 2D list python

Tags: python

I am having a two dimensional list like:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

and I want to XOR the inner sub-lists with each other. So at some point of time with some combination I will be getting a sub list with all zeros like `[0,0,0,0]` and if I don't get with two sub lists I have to go for XORing of three sub-lists till I get again `[0,0,0,0]`, if not then, have to go for four sub-lists.

The problem is I can do like picking up two lists and XOR each element then save it in separate sub-list and this works but each time I have to change my code so is there any way to XOR sub-list like `[1, 1, 0, 0] ^ [1, 0, 1, 0]` instead of doing like `lis[i][j]^lis[i+1][j]` so that I can manage my code recursively?

Comment: Are you using numpy by chance..?

Comment: no I am not using numpy

Comment: So where does the insert value dynamically part come in?

Comment: Just to clarify what you're asking: Are you trying to XOR each element from one sublist against the corresponding element from another sublist? e.g. take `[0,0,0,0]` and `[1,1,0,0]` and get `[0^1,0^1,0^0,0^0]` which equals `[1,1,0,0]`? If so, which sublists are you XOR-ing with which other sublists?

Comment: Can you include the code you're using so far?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to convert the **2-D bit** lists to a **1-D number** list and then `XOR` them together.

```
a = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
b = map(lambda x: int("".join(map(lambda y: str(y), x)),2), a)


b is now: [12, 10, 6, 14, 14, 6, 15]
```

Now you are working with a **1-D** list which will make that easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could find shorter but I think this would work:

```
STOP=[0,0,0,0]

def nxor(l,res=None,p=1):
    if not res: res= l[0]
    if res == STOP:
        return p-1 # or l[:p]
    try:
        return nxor(l,list(iter.imap (operator.xor, *list([res,l[p]]) )),p+1)
    except:
        return None # or res 

print nxor (l)
```

It returns the position of the last sub-list that lead to [0,0,0,0]; it would be easy to return the sub-list instead, or the actual result (see comments).

If you want to test all the combinations, you could use itertools:

```
for i in xrange(2,len(l)):
    for j in itertools.combinations(l,i):
        print nxor(list(j))
```